# How to plot the minimum mean of plot Horizontal Integral projection?

Tags: matlab, plot, minimum, mean

I have to make a plot (with matrix M N)from binary image. I use Horizontal Integral Projection which to find the mean of the rows. After that, I want the minimum mean coordinate make a horizontal line.

How to make the horizontal line?

Comment: I am not sure from the question what you are trying to achieve, but if you have a image `img` of matrix M x N, you can loop through the rows and do sum(img(i,:)) to get the Horizontal Projection Profile (HPP)

Comment: What have you tried? If you show some code, you are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are asking, but here's a bit of code that might help. It sums the rows of the image, finds the minimum sum, then plots the image plus a horizontal line over the row with the minimum sum.

```
x = rand(50);
[~,i] = min(sum(x,2));
figure
imagesc(x)
hold on
plot(xlim, [i i], 'w')
```

Comment: Thanks...  I have to try on that. I use the HIP for seperate between the teeth jaws. After that, I need to seperate teeth by teeth at every jaw, I've had to read from journal that they used Vertical Integral projection, may be this quite difficult than HIP.. May I ask anybody know about VIP? Sincerely